# AAD AcquireToken returns error AADSTS50000

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

We use Azure Active Directory to secure our Azure hosted APIs. These APIs are consumed by Azure hosted Angular applications. Mocst of the APIs are implemented as an ASP.NET WebAPI, some of them are now implemented using Azure Functions.

We've been securing our applications this way for the past couple of years and haven't had any issues. We were already granting access to one application based on tokens for the other by adding them to the allowed audiences, which was working fine. Currently, we're running into an issue while implementing a new scenario.

**The issue**
We have two applications: the current application (*cur*) and the targeted application (*tar*). All of our users can login to *cur*. The backend for *cur* gets a token to access *tar* based on the token the user got for *cur*. This works for users that are backed by an Azure Active Directory, either ours or a federated one. As soon as users log in that are *not* backed by an Azure Active Directory (which means they are backed by a Microsoft account), getting the token for *tar* fails with a `AADSTS50000: There was an error issuing a token`.

**Context**
Our applications are hosted in a different AAD tenant than where our users and applications are registered. The users and app registrations *are* in the same AAD tenant. We don't think this is an issue, since the configuration *is* working for AAD backed accounts.

We're using [AuthenticationContext.AcquireTokenAsync(String, ClientCredential, UserAssertion)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.identitymodel.clients.activedirectory.authenticationcontext.acquiretokenasync?view=azure-dotnet#Microsoft_IdentityModel_Clients_ActiveDirectory_AuthenticationContext_AcquireTokenAsync_System_String_Microsoft_IdentityModel_Clients_ActiveDirectory_ClientCredential_Microsoft_IdentityModel_Clients_ActiveDirectory_UserAssertion_) to get a token to access *tar* with the following parameters:

- ID of *tar* application
- ID and Key of *cur*
- Token of the current user for *cur*

We're seeing one major difference between the original tokens for AAD backed accounts and Microsoft account backed accounts: the IDP (IdentityProvider) field is different. For Microsoft account backed accounts, the IDP is `live.com`. For AAD backed accounts, this is `https://sts.windows.net/<guid>`.

We've created several test accounts, both in our AAD and external ones, to make sure it's not an issue related to our existing user accounts. Using different configurations for our `AuthenticationContext` or `ClientCredential` does not solve the issue.

Any ideas?

Comment: Asking the obvious question: Are all the NON-AAD backed users imported into both AAD tenants?

Comment: Thanks @Mötz, I just checked and I worded it wrong: the users and app registrations are in the same AAD, the applications are _hosted_ in a different one.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong. You have Tenant1 and Tenant2. Tenant1 hosts your CUR and TAR applications. Tenant2 contains all your users and Application Registrations. Users created directly as AAD users in Tenant2 works like expected, with the correct configuration. Your NON-AAD users are imported as guests into Tenant2. Is that correctly understood?

Comment: Although the initial question did imply that, this is _not_ the scenario. I also updated the question a bit to make it more clear: the app registrations and users are _defined_ in Tenant 1, the applications are _hosted_ in Tenant 2. Both AAD backed and external users are in Tenant 1.

Comment: I wouldn't expect external users (live.com / etc) users that are imported to Tenant1 to be able to access anything in Tenant2 without **explicit** being imported into Tenant2. They don't live inside Tenant1, they are just guest to that tenant. Can you try and see if importing a external user to Tenant2 makes a difference?

Comment: Just tried your suggestion. Unfortunately this doesn't solve the issue.

Comment: I would really like to help, but I need some more details about why the design is like it is and what you want to achieve with bringing the user token into play. Could we recreate the scenario with 2 simple applications that you could share with us to play around with?

Comment: Which claim in the token are you getting the details for the IDP? The "iss" claim?

Answer (score 0):

Inviting users as guest will work, but if thats not a practical option, you'd need to add support for MSA accounts in your apps/services. This is possible via the Azure AD v2.0 endpoint.

The document [Comparing the Azure AD v2.0 endpoint with the v1.0 endpoint](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/azure-ad-endpoint-comparison) has a lot of details that you'd need to learn before you start making the changes.

Try out a few of the samples available at [Azure Active Directory code samples (v2.0 endpoint)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/sample-v2-code) to gain a good understanding.

A short summary of changes that you'd be making

1. Use the newer MSAL library instead of ADAL.
2. Use [scopes instead of resource](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/azure-ad-endpoint-comparison#scopes-not-resources)
3. Use the new [App registration (Preview) portal.](https://ms.portal.azure.com/#blade/Microsoft_AAD_IAM/ActiveDirectoryMenuBlade/RegisteredAppsPreview)
4. Update your app registrations to support both AAD and MSA accounts. See *signInAudience* in [Azure Active Directory app manifest](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/reference-app-manifest).

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't answer te actual question.

Comment: I appreciate the effort you've put in writing a detailed questions, but it'd help if you can please expand the following bits 
"Our applications are hosted in a different AAD tenant than where our users and applications are registered." -> Apps are only registered in AAD and can be hosted in any Azure subscription. Unless the apps are multi-tenant and provisioned in other tenants, these apps will only be able to get tokens issued for the users in the AAD tenant where they are 'registered'.

Comment: If inviting every MSA user is not an option, then what I've suggested is what you'd need to do to support users from both AAD tenants and MSA.